# How to combine results by column with filters

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following tables: Podcast and Show, both has the 'active' column which is boolean

I need to retrieve latest active 6 podcasts, which are associated to active shows.

I tried the below query:

```
select * 
from `podcasts` 
where `active` = true 
and exists (select * 
            from `shows` 
            where `podcasts`.`show_id` = `shows`.`id` 
            and `active` = true
            ) 
and `id` in (select max(id) from `podcasts` group by `show_id`) 
order by `id` desc 
limit 6
```

It works, however, if the latest podcast is inactive, it ignores the whole show, doesn't get the latest 'active' one.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Please tell me what data do you exactly need? I posted the required database tables and columns

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

You join each active show with the latest active podcast for this show and then get the most recent 6 rows:

```sql
    select pd.* 
    from shows
    left join (select * from podcasts where show_id = shows.id and podcasts.active order by podcasts.id desc limit 1) as pd on pd.show_id = shows.id
    where shows.active and pd.active
    order by pd.id desc limit 6
```

Comment: It doesn't get unique podcast for each show, I need only latest podcast per show

Comment: You stated that you need the latest 6 podcast - not the most latest 1 podcast.

Comment: Yes, maybe I didn't clarify myself right. I need 6 latest podcasts, uniquely by show, so if I have 10 shows in database, I need latest 6 podcasts, each from different show